# relation "flow_state_created_at_idx" already exists on supabase initial migration

Tags: sql, postgresql, continuous-integration, github-actions, supabase

I've been developing locally with supabase for some weeks and now I decided to create a staging environment and add a new workflow to my pipeline.

I did exactly like the [docs](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/cli/managing-environments#configure-github-actions) said, but I'm getting the following error.

```
Error: ERROR: relation "flow_state_created_at_idx" already exists (SQLSTATE 42P07)
At statement 0: CREATE INDEX flow_state_created_at_idx ON auth.flow_state USING btree (created_at DESC)
```

I'm not sure what this means, specially because the first migration was auto generated by the supabase cli itself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you be able to open an Github issue about this one?
https://github.com/supabase/cli

Comment: I have the same issue I posted a bug ticket on Github here. https://github.com/supabase/cli/issues/1359
Seems like its a conflict creating an index, I tried dropping the index and deploying again but that didnt work